# Sql Server 2008 Install

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, installation

I already have Visual Studio 2008 installed.  When installing developer Sql Server 2008, do I need to check the Business Intelligence Development Studio option?  I'm guessing not.

I assume if I already have VS 2008, the install will just add the relevant Sql Server related project types into VS 2008.

**EDIT:**

I marked the question answered before I did the install - I've installed Sql Server before and I thought this was what happened, but on doing this install, leaving the BI studio option unchecked does **NOT** install the SQL Server projects in Visual Studio.  I had to go back and install it, so the answer is... Check it!

I was overthinking the install - it's smart enough not to install VS twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, installing BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) will add project templates for Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects.

Both Visual Studio and BIDS are the same IDE otherwise.

I hope this helps.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have [plausible] use of interest in the BI features of SQL2008, you safely exclude the Business Intelligence Studio from the installation.  Also, no worries, would you change your mind you can always install this at a later date.  It doesn't affect the way SQL Server per-se is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

[Install : SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150192/install-sql-server-business-intelligence-development-studio/1150213#1150213)